# Block Google Analytics tracking in specific URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My website is running a lot of test pages for specific purposes. Problem is I don't want to count these session and page views in Google Analytics, because we will have lots of false traffic. So I need to block these traffic data in Google Analytics.

**Notice 1**: Exclude IP filter won't work. We use VPN for these test pages. We also test it anywhere.

**Notice 2**: Custom Reports or Segment or anything are not recommended here. I know how to do this but don't want to do.

**Notice 3**: Website is Wordpress but I can't access to edit htaccess or  to remove GA analytics.js.

**Notice 4**: I am able to use Google Tag Manager. Any Tag Manager tips are welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where are you doing the actual reporting? I would honestly suggest that is a better place to put the filtering (e.g. in Google Data Studio) - far more flexible & does not require edit access to the HTML/javascript or (as you say) to .htaccess. Incidentally I don't agree with @DalmTo, this feels like a programming (reporting) matter to me.

Comment: Is the google analytics being called from the Tag Manager? If so, why not just adding exception rules for the trigger?

Comment: MandyShaw, would you guide me through the filter process?
Shir Gans, no, analytics.js is added to <head> manually

Comment: @Brucey It all depends on what reporting mechanism you are using. Is it Google Data Studio (GDS)? If so, you just need to add a GDS filter that omits your test page(s), and apply it to all the relevant controls. If it's another reporting mechanism, you need to identify it for us.

Comment: @Brucey I would nonetheless look at changing your overall approach to use Google Tag Manager, as everyone else is saying - dead easy to use (even for Javascript novices like me) & you only ever need to change the Javascript on your pages once.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I don't use GDS. I'm just a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Google Tag Manager and set up rules based on URL in triggers.

UPD In case of hardcoded GA, you can use custom filter in GA View: exclude traffic from Request URLs.

Comment: My website don't use tag manager to fire analytics.js, so it won't help

Comment: Sorry, but you wrote "I am able to use Google Tag Manager. Any Tag Manager tips are welcomed." In you case you can use custom filter in GA View: exclude traffic from Request URLs (if you know mask of your testing URLs).